# Mesh Object Output doesn't work with edges in Blender Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to use Combine Mesh to make a simple line. I have two Vertex Locations connected to the input, and the output connected to Mesh Object Output. This shows two points in the desired mesh, as expected. If I try to then feed it a list containing one edge index [0,1], the vertices disappear and no line is drawn.

I also can't get Line Mesh to work, for presumably the same reason.

What's going wrong?

Below works as expected, but connecting the Edges Indices List to Edges Indices doesn't work.

[image: combine mesh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

[image]

Remember: a vertex and an edge will not be shown in object mode. So just go to edit mode so you can see your vertices and edges.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. "Calculate Loose Edges" in Mesh Object Output was unchecked which meant the edges did not appear in object mode.